# Why UIDocumentMenuViewController does not accept kUTTypeText?

Tags: ios, string, swift, icloud

I saw in [this](http://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/posts/2014/09/18/ios8-day-by-day-day-28-document-picker) tutorial and also in [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentPickerProgrammingGuide/AccessingDocuments/AccessingDocuments.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014451-CH2-SW2), that this bunch of code should work.

```
let d = UIDocumentMenuViewController(documentTypes: [kUTTypeText as NSString], inMode: .Import)
o.delegate = self
self.presentViewController(d, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But I get a compile time error

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[`kUTTypeText`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/MobileCoreServices/Reference/UTTypeRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/UTI_Text_Types) is defined in the MobileCoreServices framework, so you should add

```
import MobileCoreServices
```

Also, as Bartłomiej correctly noticed, the type identifier has to be converted
from `CFString` to `String` in Swift 2/Xcode 7:

```
UIDocumentMenuViewController(documentTypes: [kUTTypeText as String], inMode: .Import)
```

Comment: for Swift you need to cast it also: `documentTypes: [String(kUTTypeText)]`

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk: You are right (one of the many things that constantly change between Swift releases :) – Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @MartinR **Thank you**, What a big shame that this essential information "import MobileCoreServices" no where on apple documentation!

Comment: Android Studio would offer to automatically add the required imports in such cases 

Comment: Is there any place within the Apple frameworks that defines the type identifiers as Swift strings to eliminate the casting?

Comment: @Klaas: None that I know of.